# MOV BX,[SI] - ASM question

Tags: assembly, x86, 16-bit, mov

I'm studying ASM 8086 theoretically on highschool.
And when I do this:

`MOV BX,[SI]`

 is SI+1 going to BH or BL?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4):

The byte at memory location `SI + 1` will be stored in the register `BH` because x86 is [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is about the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of x86, and the answer is that it is little-endian: the byte at address SI goes to BL. The byte at SI+1 goes to BH.